# my div won't appear but others will

Tags: html, css

As I enter the styling for my `#sideBar` div nothing appears... I have tried using the z-index property but nothing seems to be working either. Basically, what I want is to have a black sidebar to the left of my page with those specific dimensions. I am guessing I have written something wrong somewhere but I cannot pinpoint my error.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Noam's Website</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="backgroundCover"></div>
        <div id="sideBar"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(images/background2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
#backgroundCover {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
#sideBar {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: When this is exactly your code, then the CSS is in the wrong place. Put it inside `<head>` between a `<style>` and `</style>` tag...

Answer (score 1):

It appears for me down below. What is it that you are trying to achieve? Do you want your sidebar to be on top of the gray background?

If so, add the following to `#sideBar`

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

I am not sure what your use case is for *IDs*, but in most cases I would recommend using *classes* over *IDs* due to *specificity*.

Specificity refers to the weight that is given to your CSS declarations. Declaring styles for your elements by using *IDs* will make it very hard to overwrite them if you need to do so.

You can find more on specificity on the following pages

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity
2. https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

### Example

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(images/background2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
.backgroundCover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
.sideBar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Noam's Website</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="backgroundCover"></div>
  <div class="sideBar"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That is what I want! This has rarely happened before... I guess it might be my text editor then... @Jason

Comment: @NoamSuissa Welcome! I expanded on my answer and included a bit on *CSS specificity*. Did that solve your question?

Comment: Thank you for the help and the articles! Your solution resolved the problem. Reversing the order of my two divs worked as well. @Jason

Comment: @NoamSuissa That's great! You're welcome! If you need any help, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You have put as width 100%. So it overlaps over the other. Give a padding-left 50px to it. Take a look https://jsfiddle.net/vyt18hh5/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Noam's Website</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="sideBar"></div>
  <div id="backgroundCover"></div>
</body>
</html>

html{
height: 100%;
}
body{
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-image: url(images/background2.jpg);
background-size: cover;
}
#backgroundCover{
height: 100%;
background-color: blue;
z-index:1;
padding-left:50px;
}
#sideBar{
width: 50px;
height: 100%;
float: left;
background-color: black;
z-index:2;
}
```